# Unable to use Tenda USB Antenna

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb

So, guys. I just bought recently an antenna from Tenda. When I plug it in, the Ubuntu seems to conflict between two drivers.  Here are two driver that Ubuntu listed:

> Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] **and**  Ralink 802.11n WLAN

I do not sure what is my Tenda, but it is an antenna.

P/S: When I plugged it in and disable the WiFi card, both driver were reported that 'Hardware Disabled' even I didn't touch it. And when I open Network setting, Ubuntu didn't do anything (I guess). And here is what I recieved when I do `lsusb`:

```
diamond@diavilion:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 056e:00ca Elecom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

This is the [Front](http://s24.postimg.org/7h7njcdgl/IMG_0005.jpg) and the [Model (Back)](http://s24.postimg.org/r1m6m4e1x/IMG_0007.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to disable the internal wireless device, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwl3945"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r iwl3945
exit
```

You should be all set.